# WCF Service singleton get instance

Tags: asp.net, wcf, singleton

I have a WCF service running with ASP.NET compatibility.

This service is supposed to be readonly and is created using web script factory.

I want to get the singleton instance from anywhere in code (different pages.. etc), and if it's not created it should be created, but if accessed directly for first time it shouldn't create another singleton instance if there was one already created from somewhere in code. Basically, I want a classic singleton, but not using static and the creation of the service should be the factory's job.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an attribute on your wcf service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)] 
class MySingleton : ...
{...}
```

With this your WCF service has a single instance, that is used by all callers.

For details see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx

Comment: and how ill i get a reference to the singleton instance from other places? NOTE:on the server i want to directly use the .net object not create a client proxy..